# find angle in triangle with python

Tags: python

i try to find an angle of triangle with rules:
If the total of the three numbers = 180, then check again:
If the three corners of the triangle form an acute angle with a magnitude between 0 ° to 90 °, then print the words "acute angle"
If one of the corners is an obtuse angle whose magnitude is between 90 ° to 180 °, then print the words "obtuse angle"
If one of the corners is a right angle whose magnitude is 90 °, then print the words "carpenter's triangle"
If the total of the three numbers is not 180, then print the words "NOT TRIANGLE"

this my program but i got wrong output:

```
A = int(input("enter the number of 1 : "))
B = int(input("enter the number of 2 : "))
C = int(input("enter the number of 3 : "))

if(A+B+C <= 90):
    print("acute angle")
if(  90>A<=180 or 90>B<=180 or 90>C<=180 ):
    print("obtuse angle")
if(A+B+C > 180):
    print("NOT TRIANGLE")
    break
if(A==90 or B==90 or C==90):
    print("carpenter's triangle")
```

i need your opinion to fix this program

Comment: Can you please explain which part is not working?
Can you provide sample input and outputs which is not correct?

Comment: Please say what `wrong output` you are seeing. Also, I expect the `break` to give you an error.

Comment: What's the deal with `<=180`? Are you sure an angle of a triangle can be 180 degrees?

Comment: if iinput A = 90 B= 90 and C = 90 it should NOT TRIANGLE  not an carpenter's triangle but i my program its print carpenter's triangle

Comment: See the answer by @Amiga500.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, If I understand you right:

```
if A+B+C != 180:
    #Cannot be a triangle
    print("Not triangle, please enter new values")
else:
    #We can proceed as its a viable entry
    if A < 90 and B < 90 and C < 90:
        print("Acute Angle")
    elif A == 90 or B == 90 or C == 90:
        print("Carpenter's triangle")
    elif A > 90 or B > 90 or C > 90:
        print("Obtuse angle")
    else:
        print("Some other scenario we haven't accounted for")
```

As your logic stands, you are never getting into your print("acute angle") scenario for a valid triangle.

Comment: the input only return not triangle

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: i input A = 90, B =30, and C = 10 it should obtuse trinangle, in your program it show not triangle

Comment: A triangle has 3 angles, that have to add up to 180. Given that your input triangle's angles only equal 130, the program is correct in rejecting your triangle

Answer (score 0):

Your if conditions are incorrect. And you should use elif instead of if without first if. Because a triangle can't be acute and obtuse at the same time.

```py
A = int(input("enter the number of 1 : "))
B = int(input("enter the number of 2 : "))
C = int(input("enter the number of 3 : "))

if A+B+C != 180 or A<0 or A>180 or B<0 or B>180 or C<0 or C>180:
    print("NOT TRIANGLE")

elif A<90 and B<90 and C<90:
    print("acute angle")

elif (A>90 and A<180) or (B>90 and B<180) or (C>90 and C<180):
    print("obtuse angle")

elif A==90 or B==90 or C==90:
    print("carpenter's triangle")

else:
    print("Wut?")
```

Comment: wrong bro, if i input A = 90, B =30, and C = 10 it should obtuse trinangle, in your program it show not triangle

Comment: If A=90, B=30, and C=10 it isn't a triangle. The sum of angles of a triangle is always equal to 180.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution you can try:

```
# If sum of angles makes upto 180; then a triangle 
if(A+B+C == 180):
  # if atleast one side is 90; then Carpenter's triangle
  if(A==90 or B==90 or C==90):
    print("Carpenter's triangle")
  # if all sides are less than 90; then Accute triangle
  elif(A<90 and B<90 and C<90):
    print("Accute triangle")
  # if atleast one side is greater than 90; then Obtuce triangle
  elif(90>A<=180 or 90>B<=180 or 90>C<=180):
    print("Obtuse triangle")
else:
    print('Not a triangle')
```

[image: If the three corners of the triangle form an acute angle with a magnitude between 0 ° to 90 °, then print the words "acute angle" If one of the corners is an obtuse angle whose magnitude is between 90 ° to 180 °, then print the words "obtuse angle" If one of the corners is a right angle whose magnitude is 90 °, then print the words "carpenter's triangle" If the total of the three numbers is not 180, then print the words "NOT TRIANGLE"]

- If at least one angle is 90; then it can't be an acute or obtuse
  triangle
- If all sides are less than 90; then it can't be an obtuse triangle
- Hense the the if-else flow